# How can I make Fluid+Cloth animation togather?

Tags: animation, modifiers, fluid-simulation, cloth-simulation

I've used Cloth modifier and then Fluid modifier.

But result doesn't looks like as I expected.....

The fluid is stopped by the cloth mesh(As a plane before it animate cloth simulation). Domain size is big enough....

How can I make the fluid follow the cloth surface?

(I've applied Cloth modifier to the plane with pins for all 4 corners and applied Fluid modifier obstacle type)

Thanks in advance.......[image: RENDERED IMAGE]

Comment: As far as I know it isn't possible they are two different solvers.

Comment: You could probably bake cloth simulation to frames then use it as collision for fluid.

Comment: @LukeD How can I bake cloth simulation?

Comment: Under the physics tab in "cache" there is a bake button. Do this for both the cloth and fluid physics and check if that works.

Comment: I'll prepare answer later for you.